# dataWithContentsOfURL taking a long time to return with numerous words in url

Tags: ios, objective-c, url, nsdata

I have this code which downloads the contents of the url. The contents of the url is simply a link to another url, and thus shouldn't take long to download at all:

```
NSString *additional = @"test string"; 
NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://tts-api.com/tts.mp3?&return_url=1&q=%@", additional];
    NSLog(@"string: %@", urlString);
    NSString *modifiedURLString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"modified url string: %@", modifiedURLString);
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:modifiedURLString];
    NSLog(@"url: %@", url);
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSLog(@"data length: %i", data.length);
```

The data always takes around 20 seconds to return, and the length it comes out with is always small (as it should be). Here's the log:

```
string: http://tts-api.com/tts.mp3?&return_url=1&q=test string
modified url string: http://tts-api.com/tts.mp3?&return_url=1&q=test%20string
url: http://tts-api.com/tts.mp3?&return_url=1&q=test%20string
data length: 69
```

Interestingly, if i make the additional string be a single word, such as "test", it works through this in a fraction of a second.

Any ideas why having multiple words is slowing me down?

Comment: The behavior is same when using a browser. Looks like a possible bug on the website.

Comment: @Mar0ux Alright, i'll let them know.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the web service that is taking so long to generate the answer, there is nothing you can do in your code to make it faster. But you really should not be using `dataWithContentsOfURL:` to load data from a remote server since you have no control over how long this takes. If you do this on the main thread your app will get killed by the watchdog timer if the request takes too long.

Use the URL loading system and have the request run asynchronously. Here is the simple variant:

```
[NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest: [NSURLRequest requestWithURL: url] 
                                   queue: [NSOperationQueue mainQueue] 
                       completionHandler: ^( NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error ) { 
    // Process response in this log
}];
```

Comment: Nice use of the Method, I didn't know that this method will download file so fast. We can save *data value too at the same time without loss of data. Nice work Cheers!!